# How to type a callback function received in another function in reason of it's arguments in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, callback, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Ok, so, maybe the title of the question isn't too intuitive, but I don't know how to exactly ask it.

My problem is, I have a function that receives a callback function as one of it's arguments and the arguments to be passed to this callback and the function that receives the callback function will call the **.call** method of the received callback function and will return it's return.

I want to know if it's is even possible to type it instead of using any, like the exemples bellow:

**How my actual function is**

```
public static executeBlockingFunction(callbackFunction: Function,
    callbackArguments: Array<any>): any{
    // execute some code before calling the callback function
    
    const callbackReturn = callbackFunction.call(callbackFunction, ...callbackArguments);

    // executes some more code before returning the callback return
   
    return callbackReturn;  
}
```

**How I want it to be, with generics**

```
public static executeBlockingFunction<maybe some generic here, I don't know>(callbackFunction: <somehow the type of the callback function>,
    callbackArguments: Array<<the actual types of the arguments of the callback function>>): <the return type of the callback function> {
    // execute some code before calling the callback function
    
    const callbackReturn = callbackFunction.call(callbackFunction, ...callbackArguments);

    // executes some more code before returning the callback return
   
    return callbackReturn;
}
```

With the generic form that I want, when someone call the *executeFunction* will get as return the exactly return type as if they calling directly the callback function

In the TypeScript documentation, I found some utilities type that may can help achieve this, but I have no idea on how to implement it:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a generic parameter `F` that is constrained to `(...args: any[]) => any` (that is, `F` must satisfy the type `(...args: any[]) => any`). Then you'll be able to use the utility types you found:

```
public static executeBlockingFunction<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(callbackFunction: F, callbackArguments: Parameters<F>): ReturnType<F> {
```

Comment: That's exactly what I expected, thank you! ❤